# Show admin bar only for some USERS roles

Tags: users, admin-bar, user-roles

I have 4 users roles on my wordpress platform (role1, role2, role3, role4)

I'm looking for to show front-end top bar only for Role1 Role2.

how can i add a condition on this code to show it only for this 2 roles?

```
function wpc_show_admin_bar() {
  return true;
}
add_filter('show_admin_bar' , 'wpc_show_admin_bar');
```

thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can disable the admin bar via function:

```
show_admin_bar(false);
```

So with that in mind, we can hook into `after_setup_theme` and hide the admin bar for all users except `administrator` and `contributor`:

```
function cc_wpse_278096_disable_admin_bar() {
   if (current_user_can('administrator') || current_user_can('contributor') ) {
     // user can view admin bar
     show_admin_bar(true); // this line isn't essentially needed by default...
   } else {
     // hide admin bar
     show_admin_bar(false);
   }
}
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'cc_wpse_278096_disable_admin_bar');
```

I am only using `administrator` and `contributor` as example. You can of course change this and add more roles.

Answer (score 4):

I see many people using the `after_setup_theme` action instead of the `show_admin_bar` filter, but this one works as well. I would say that the only difference is that the filter might be overwritten, but I see nothing wrong in that.

```php
function wpc_show_admin_bar() {
    // Add the roles to exclude from having admin bar.
    $excluded_roles = [ 'role3', 'role4' ];

    return is_user_logged_in() && ! array_intersect( wp_get_current_user()->roles, $excluded_roles);
}
add_filter('show_admin_bar', 'wpc_show_admin_bar');
```

Nice and easy, you just need to add the roles you want to the `$excluded_roles` array. The function will only return true if the user is logged in and it doesn't have any of the excluded roles.