# disable wp admin bar for customers logged in

Tags: admin-bar

I have a wordpress website, where i am providing customers with user name and password to access my shop.

When a customer logs in, he can see the top wordpress admin bar as well. I dont want users added as "customers" through users>add new to see that bar.

How should i disable this?

Comment: Found a [tutorial](http://jeroensormani.com/hiding-the-admin-bar/). Just find what user role or capability your 'customers' hold and simply put that in `current_user_can('here')`. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show admin bar only for some USERS roles](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/278096/show-admin-bar-only-for-some-users-roles)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at user profile in WordPress administration you would see that there is an option: **Show Toolbar when viewing site**. If you uncheck this option user will not see an admin bar.

This option is checked by default when user is registering to your store. You can disable it using `user_register` filter.

```
function wpse_278096_disable_admin_bar( $user_id ) {

    update_user_meta($user_id, 'show_admin_bar_front', false);
}

add_action( 'user_register', 'wpse_278096_disable_admin_bar', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: i have added this using php inserter plugin, below another php function (for another purpose). But it doesnt work as expected.

Comment: it has disabled the "show toolbar when viewing site" but by default when i login using that account, it shows the top wordpress bar still.

Comment: Maybe some of installed plugin is overwriting this settings? Try to disable all plugins and check if admin bar is visible for user which has "Show Toolbar when viewing site" unchecked.

Comment: yes it worked. One plugin was interfering. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the below code to your theme function.php file and you should be good.

```
add_action('set_current_user', 'customer_hide_admin_bar');
function customer_hide_admin_bar() {
  if (!current_user_can('edit_posts')) {
    add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_false');

  }
}
```

Comment: i have added this using php inserter plugin, below another php function (for another purpose). But it doesnt work as expected.